# What is a Transition Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, science

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Transition Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Transition}\ }
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[#fcce8d]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  court}&\text{       king}\\ \hline
\text{  finite}&\text{       infinite}\\ \hline
\text{  gale}&\text{       storm}\\ \hline
\text{  hen}&\text{       rooster}\\ \hline
\text{  italic}&\text{       bold}\\ \hline
\text{  literal}&\text{       fictional}\\ \hline
\text{  miscalculations}&\text{       indefectible}\\ \hline
\text{  obstructiveness}&\text{       facilitatory}\\ \hline
\text{  parenthesizing}&\text{       ungrouping}\\ \hline
\text{  racism}&\text{       hate}\\ \hline
\text{  sensitivity}&\text{       perceptiveness}\\ \hline
\text{  superconductors}&\text{       semiconductor}\\ \hline
\text{  taxi}&\text{    cab   }\\ \hline
\text{  unread}&\text{  rewrite     }\\ \hline
\text{  wearing}&\text{ dressing      }\\ \hline
\text{  yolk}&\text{    white   }\\ \hline
\text{  zodiacs}&\text{  gemini     }\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}$$

CSV version:

```
Transition Words™, Not Transition Words™
court;king
finite;infinite
gale;storm
hen;rooster
italic;bold
literal;fictional
miscalculations;indefectible
obstructiveness;facilitatory
parenthesizing;ungrouping
racism;hate
sensitivity;perceptiveness
superconductors;semiconductor
taxi;cab
unread;rewrite
wearing;dressing
yolk;white
zodiacs;gemini
```

These are not the only examples of Transition words™, many more exists.
**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint 1

> Only the spelling of the words matters: their meanings, fonts, capitalization... is not important

Comment: I have a speculation, but I think it is leading me toward false paths: by any chance, is the property of a transition word related to the rot13(genafvgvba ryrzragf va gur crevbqvp gnoyr)?

Comment: @oalt no sorry.

Comment: Any hints? It has been 3 days already.

Comment: @CulverKwan the problem is that it is difficult to give hints without spoiling the solution

Comment: The body and CSV versions disagree on the last word. Is it 'zodiac' or 'zodiacs'?

Comment: @GabrielG thank you, I've edited the post. It is "zodiacs" (also 'zodiac' is **not** a transition word)

Comment: @CulverKwan I've added an hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transition word™ is one such that

> the sum of its letter ($A=1$, $B=2$ $\dots$, $Z=26$) is equal to the temperature of [the melting point or boiling point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements) of some chemical element. The temperatures are measured in Kelvin and rounded to the nearest integer number.

For example

> **court** sums up to $77$. The boiling point of Nitrogen is $77.36 K$. 
>  **taxi** sums up to $54$. The melting point of Oxygen is $54.36 K$. 
>  **superconductors** sums up to $211$. The boiling point of Radon is $211.3 K$.

and so on...

They are called Transition words™ because

> the rule to determine whether a word is a Transition word™ or not is related to the temperature of the points of phase transition of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

> Transition Words™ can have plural forms :P; a more in depth view would 
> consider Not Transition Words™ to be "greater" conceptually compared to Transition Words™  (set inclusion comes to mind) even though this does not apply to zodiac <-> gemini. 
>  I haven't taken into account syntax (number of letters, pos in alphabet, etc.)
>  Am I on the right track?
>  Is the rule semantic, syntactic (involving character manipulation, word length, etc.), visual (outline of the words creates shapes, etc.)?
>  Are these the only words that can conform to the rule?

Comment: Kings, Roosters, Storms.......?

Comment: no sorry, this is not the right track

Comment: @El-Guest read the answer again, then the exact form of the not transition words.

Comment: @melfnt I've added a few questions in the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't use the answers to ask clarification. Though I'm sorry you do not have enough reputation to comment here. I'll edit the post to reply your questions